# recaptcha not sending email after verify in php

Tags: php, email, recaptcha

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email=$_POST['email'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!$captcha)
{
  echo 'Please check the the captcha form.';
}

$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/sitev    erify?secret="secretkey"      &response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($response.success==false)
{
  header('Location:http://mywebsite.com/.errordocs/404.html');
}
else
{
  header('Location:http://mywebsite.com/thankyou.php');
}
}

if (isset ($_POST['Side_Form'])){

$name = $_POST['name'];

$last = $_POST['last'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$comments = $_POST['comments'];
// Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with Enjoy's    contact e-mail)

$to = 'somebody@somewhere.com';

$subject = "Main Contact Form";

$message = "Name: $name

Email: $email

Phone: $phone

Comments: $comments";

$headers = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

The problem is when the recaptcha is verified on the form, it displays the checkmark, user can click submit, but I get a blank screen and email doesn't send. Any help is Greatly appreciated, have been working on this for about 3 weeks.

Comment: because you redirect away from the page befor you send any email

Answer (score 1):

your currently redirecting before actually sending the email. here is your code restructured. also fixed the recaptcha response processing

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    if (! $captcha){
        echo 'Please check the the captcha form.';
        exit();
    }else{

        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secretkey . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if (intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1){
            header('Location:http://mywebsite.com/.errordocs/404.html');
            exit();
        }else{


            if (isset($_POST['Side_Form'])){//not sure what this is, hopefully you do :-)

                $name = $_POST['name'];

                $last = $_POST['last'];

                $email = $_POST['email'];

                $phone = $_POST['phone'];

                $comments = $_POST['comments'];
                // Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with Enjoy's contact e-mail)

                $to = 'somebody@somewhere.com';

                $subject = "Main Contact Form";

                $message = "Name: $name
Email: $email
Phone: $phone
Comments: $comments";

                $headers = "From: $email \r\n";

                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                header('Location:http://mywebsite.com/thankyou.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help! I pasted the code provided, but now I get this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '6' (T_LNUMBER)